# upload image and store it into my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

i'm trying to create form to upload an image and store it into my database 
but i got these problem:
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\confee\admin\upload.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\confee\admin\upload.php on line 8

Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\confee\admin\upload.php on line 8
File is not an image.Sorry, file already exists.
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\confee\admin\upload.php on line 23
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

---

### this is the code that i used to create the form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

---

### and this is upload.php file

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'connect.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

---

### i'm really stuck in this problem i hope someone help me

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Code should work properly.
before pressing upload button select a image file to be uploaded.
If not it will show the above error.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a bit? For example, did you actually try andres' code and it worked in your environment? If so, can you provide some details about your environment (e.g. versions etc). I'm probably going out on a limb because I'm about to make an assumption, but probably andres did select a file.

Comment: Yes.I did tried it on my environment it should run properly if you browse image file first and then press upload button.